# When I put a chart on my workbook with xlsxwriter, excel opens without a an open workbook or workbook

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, xlsxwriter

When I run my program without the code to create a chart, it works fine and converts from a .csv to an .xlsx and opens normally. When I include the code to create the graph it opens to a blank page without a workbook. Because of this I know the problem is with something after my write statements. 'col[]' is a list of user input strings that I am using to title each series, and 'colors[]' is a list of hex values I am using to pick the colors for each series. I have limited experience with C++ and only began learning Python a week ago so please forgive my messy code.

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook(cognomen, {'strings_to_numbers': True})
        sheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Sheet1")
        with open(file, "r") as f:
            reader = csv.reader((line.replace('\0', '') for line in f), delimiter=',')
            for r, row in enumerate(reader):
                for c, val in enumerate(row):
                    sheet.write(r, c, val)
                while v < len(my_entries):
                    sheet.write(col[v] + str(5), str(my_entries[v].get()))
                    v = v + 1
        chart = workbook.add_chart({
                'type': 'scatter',
                'subtype': 'smooth'
        })
        
        h = 0
        while h < len(my_entries):
            chart.add_series({
                'name': str(my_entries[h].get()),
                'categories': '=Sheet1!$' + str(len(my_entries) + 10) + ':$B' + str(r),
                'values': '=Sheet1!$' + col[h] + ':' + str(len(my_entries) + 10) + col[h] + str(r),
                'line': {
                    'colors': colors[h] 
                }
            })
            v = v + 1

        chart.set_plotarea({
            'border': {'color': 'black'}
        })

        chart.set_legend({
            'position': 'bottom'
        })

        chart.set_title({
            'name': new_nomen.removesuffix(".xlsx"),
            'name_font': {
                'name': 'Calibri',
                'color': '#0066CC',
                'bold': False
            }
        })

        chart.set_x_axis({
            'name': 'Time',
            'name_font': {
                'name': 'Calibri',
                'color': '#000000',
                'bold': False
            },
            'time_axis': True,
            'num_format': 'h:mm:ss',
            'min': 0,
        })

        chart.set_y_axis({
            'name': 'Temperature (' + degree_sign + 'C)',
            'name_font': {
                'name': 'Calibri',
                'color': '#000000',
                'bold': False
            },
            'min': 0,
        })

        chart.set_style(15)
        sheet.insert_chart('C1', chart, {'x_offset': 25, 'y_offset': 10})
        workbook.close()
```